# Error when the Email formencode validator

Tags: python, formencode

I wanted to create an IDN-aware formencode validator to use in one of my projects. I used a portion of code from the Django project (http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/django/core/validators.py) to do that, but there must be a trivial error in my code I can't find :

```
class Email(formencode.validators.Email):
    def _to_python(self, value, state):
        try:
            return super(Email, self)._to_python(value, state)
        except formencode.Invalid as e:
            # Trivial case failed. Try for possible IDN domain-part

            print 'heywo !'

            if value and u'@' in value:
                parts = value.split(u'@')
                try:
                    parts[-1] = parts[-1].encode('idna')
                except UnicodeError:
                    raise e

                try:
                    super(Email, self)._to_python(u'@'.join(parts), state)
                except formencode.Invalid as ex:
                    raise ex

                return value
            else:
                raise e
```

When I try to validate an email with an IDN domain (ex: test@wääl.de), the Invalid exception raised by the first call is thrown, and the portion of code after the first except is never executed ('heywo !' is never printed).

There is an example :

```
>>> from test.lib.validators import Email
>>> Email().to_python(u'test@zääz.de')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/FormEncode-1.2.3dev-py2.6.egg/formencode    /api.py", line 416, in to_python
    vp(value, state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/FormEncode-1.2.3dev-py2.6.egg/formencode    /validators.py", line 1352, in validate_python
    value, state)
Invalid: The domain portion of the email address is invalid (the portion after the @: z\xe4\xe4z.de)
```

What did I do wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the post and include the stack trace you get with the error.

Comment: I added the trace. As I said, it's just the result I would expect by calling the _original_ Email validator. Which is not the case :/

Comment: I'd look at line 1352 in validators.py as the trace reports. I suspect that whomever made that module does not correctly handle unicode domain portions. I'm also not entirely sure they're valid to begin with, but they could easily be (I don't have enough knowledge). Does it validate when you remove the unicode?

Comment: The line 1352 is basically where the formencode.Invalid exception is raised. My question, in fact, is more like : why, in _my_ code, is the outer try/except not working, and why can't I catch this exception ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found the answer. I was overloading `_to_python` instead of `validate_python`. The class now looks like :

```
class Email(formencode.validators.Email):
    def validate_python(self, value, state):
        try:
            super(Email, self).validate_python(value, state)
        except formencode.Invalid as e:
            # Trivial case failed. Try for possible IDN domain-part
            if value and u'@' in value:
                parts = value.split(u'@')
                try:
                    parts[-1] = parts[-1].encode('idna')
                except UnicodeError:
                    raise e

                try:
                    super(Email, self).validate_python(u'@'.join(parts), state)
                except formencode.Invalid as ex:
                    raise ex
            else:
                raise e
```

It's working perfectly :)

Comment: You should change the `raise e` lines to just `raise`. If you do so, it will preserve the stack trace instead of rewriting it.